# MVVM UI update after command executed dialog closes

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

Hey a similar question has been asked before, but none that answers mine exactly.

I have an MVVM aplication that includes an "Options" button - click this and the options dialog opens - this is done via a command.

Once the user has saved their options, I want to tell the main shell to reload its options. What is the best way of doing this?

My button looks like this:

```
<Button Width="50" Command="{Binding SettingsCommand}" CommandParameter="" ...>
    <Image Source="Images/Settings.png" Width="16" Height="16" />
</Button>
```

Thanks,
Dave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way is to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) on your viewmodel, and have your command fire the [PropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx) event after it's done changing properties (which in this case would be after the dialog closes). When you fire PropertyChanged, your bindings will read the new property values.

Comment: Excuse my dumbness but... I actually need to execute some real live code, not just update values. I've ended up creating an event on the view model with a listener defined in the view's code-behind. The view's listener then reloads all options (colour schemes and such) when the event is raised.

Comment: I don't understand. You're executing real live code when you show the dialog. Why can't you put your reload code there too?

Comment: When I show my dialog, I show it from my ViewModel. The problem is that I need to reload my options from my View. I have set up the application so that my ViewModel has no link back to the view. Hence, I have created an event so that the ViewModel can notify the View that the options have changed.

Having described this makes me think that the ViewModel needs to have a link to the View. That would certainly solve this problme plus about my VM greater access to the View.

Answer (score 1):

> main shell to reload its options

Thats usualy acieved using DataBinding. When you are closing this dialog, simply update values in your ViewModel and it should bind to View easily.
It looks, like your understanding of MVVM is little wrong.

Comment: For data that is directly represented on the screen (such as a text box value or a field's enable status), I would totally agree that data binding is the way to go. What I am trying to do is programatically load a set of styles into the main window. The styles then are automatically reflected in the way the screen is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest having an OptionsService that the ViewModel uses within the Dialog. Save changes to the service and if any dependent VM's need to change the display state based on the options change then they register (via an event) on the service that the options have changed. The service would also have a way to get the options data as well.

If you use Dependency Injection then this should be straight forward as you can inject an IOptionsService into all the ViewModels.